# ASP.NET MVC Posted date field comes in as 1/1/0001

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Just started working with .NET and MVC(1).  I'm having a problem wherein in my add action the entered date for some reason ends up as 1/1/0001 instead of what is entered thus causing a date overflow.

In my model, this field ("Added") is is of type datetime and does not allow nulls.

In my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Add()
    {
        Instance instance = new Instance()
        {
            Added = DateTime.Now,
            Active = true
        };

        return View(instance);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Add(Instance instance)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("test");
                instanceRepository.Add(instance);
                instanceRepository.Save();

                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = instance.InstanceID });
            }
            catch
            {
                ModelState.AddRuleViolations(instance.GetRuleViolations());
            }
        }
        return View(instance);
    }
```

And in my view I have:

```
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Added) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Added,String.Format("{0:g}",Model.Added))%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Added) %>
```

When I first go to Instances/Add the default value is set correctly, however as soon as I submit the date turns into 1/1/0001 (from my understanding this indicates that it was either null or in an unrecognizable format)

When I debug and palce a watch on Request.Form I see the date coming in encoded ie Request.Form {Added=4%2f9%2f2010+8%3a24%3a39+AM} - is this an issue?

I know its probably not enough information to make a conlusive determination on why this is failing, but if someone could provide some good debugging tips on how to determine where the submitted date is getting munged I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Html.TextBoxFor can not be in MVC 1 as you have written

Comment: Ugh - I must be using MVC 2 - had both installed and thought I was using 1 but this just goes to show how new I am to this...

Comment: You're right - properties of System.Web.MVC show version 2.0 - thanks for the heads up Gregoire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers...  The mistake turned out to be in my partial model class:

```
namespace MSSQL_Manager.Models
{
[Bind(Include="xxxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx,xxxx")]
public partial class Instance
{
    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0); }
    }
```

I didn't have the 'Added' field in the [Bind(Include="xxxx")] attribute.

Need to read up more on attributes - thanks everyone for their time

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `String.Format("{0:g}", Model.ExpirationDate)` bit above is the TemplateName parameter of the TextBoxFor method. The view engine won't be able to find a template which matches the date.

What you need to do is decorate your model

```
// inside your Instance model
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:g}")]
[DisplayName("Added")]
public DateTime Added { get; set; }
```

and then use the following in your view

```
<%= Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateRequired)%>
```

And I got this solution from [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/Q_25048095.html).

Comment: Thanks Nick - I'll check out that link

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a localization problem IMO.

See this [post](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx)